# Set InsertionPoint to end of current line in wxPython wx.TextCtrl

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxtextctrl, wxpython

Ok, so I know I can do:

```
curPos = self.LogWindow.GetInsertionPoint
lineNum = self.LogWindow.GetRange( 0, self.LogWindow.GetInsertionPoint() ).split("\n")
lineText = self.LogWindow.GetLineText(lineNum)
```

But how can I set the `InsertionPoint` to the end of the current lint?

Current line of course meaning: the line where the `InserionPoint` is currently located.

Any help appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    curPos = self.log.GetInsertionPoint()
    curCol,curRow = self.log.PositionToXY(curPos)
    lineNum = curRow
    lineText = self.log.GetLineText(lineNum)
    newPos=self.log.XYToPosition(len(lineText), curRow)
    self.log.SetInsertionPoint(newPos)
```

Comment: Thanks! One slight error: for me `self.log.PositionToXY(curPos)` returns three values: `(True, curCol, curRow)`. So I changed the second line to: `curVal,curCol,curRow = self.log.PositionToXY(curPos)`